# users are asked for password while using gitolite

Tags: gitolite

I have successfully created `gitolite-admin.git` repo on server (say) `10.107.105.13`. I can clone this repo on my local machine (say) `10.14.42.7` by issuing `git clone gitolite@10.107.105.13:gitolite-admin`. I had to add some lines in `.ssh/config` file to make sure that correct private key is used.

Then I have added a user `dilawar` to `conf/gitolite.conf` file and a appropriate key `dilawar.pub` to `keys` folder. I have added and commited this commit to the `gitolite-admin` repo. I have also added one more entry in `.ssh/conf` file so that a correct private key is used. But when I try to do `git clone dilawar@10.107.105.13:testing`, gitolite asks for the password. I am under the impression that I do not have to create user dilawar on 10.107.105.13. I have checked by logging into server that repository testing.git exists as well public-key `dilawar.pub` has been added to `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I have also tried `ssh -vvvv dilawar@10.107.105.13` to check if the correct file is being offered. Here is my `.ssh/conf` file.

```
HostName 10.107.105.13 
    User gitolite
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite

Host 10.107.105.13
    HostName 10.107.105.13 
    User dilawar 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your config file, I see:

```
User dilawar
```

That is wrong. ssh communication to a gitolite server are always done with **the same account** (here `gitolite`).
What changes is the private key used, which will help gitolite determine your identity.

What you `~/.ssh/config` file should look like is:

```
Host admin
    HostName 10.107.105.13 
    User gitolite
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite

Host dilawar
    HostName 10.107.105.13 
    User gitolite
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

For cloning `gitolite-admin`, you would use:

```
git clone admin:gitolite-admin
```

For cloning a repo `dilawar` has access to:

```
git clone dilawar:aRepo
```

See more at "[Gitolite: adding user not working, and DENIED by fallthru when cloning as root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843781/gitolite-adding-user-not-working-and-denied-by-fallthru-when-cloning-as-root/10844231#10844231)".
See also "[how gitolite uses ssh](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/glssh.html)"

> Adding your public key to the server's `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is how ssh uses pubkeys to authenticate users.
>   Let's say `sita@work.station` is trying to log in as `git@server`.
>   What you have to do is take the `~sita/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file for user `sita` on work-station and append its contents (remember it's only one line) to `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` **for user `git`** on server.
>
> The authorized_keys file can have multiple public keys (from many different people) added to it so any of them can log in to `git@server`.

Answer (score 4):

I have got it working by cloning the repository using the gitolite username.

```
git clone gitolite@server:repo
```

If keys are added successfully then further pull and push will go smoothly.

I am accepting VomC answer as a better answer.

Comment: Didn't see your answer at the time. +1 for the feedback. I have improved the formatting on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909791/26702) is the key, but I ran into an edge case that's worth mentioning for future searchers.

Even if you do everything else right, as in VonC's answer, a somewhat standard setting for `ControlPath` can mess things up.

I had two users in `~/.ssh/config`, as below:

```
Host gitolite
    HostName <whatever> 
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite

Host username
    HostName <whatever> 
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/username
```

In theory, this should have allowed me to run `git clone git@username:reponame`, but the server kept thinking that I was trying to clone the repo as the gitolite admin (who does not have permission to clone that repo), rather than as the gitolite user (who does have permission to clone the repo).

The problem was that in my all hosts section, I had the following:

```
Hosts *
    # other stuff that doesn't matter
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/ssh-%r@%h:%p
```

If you don't see it right away (I didn't!), the problem is that the expansions for `%r@%h%p` (= `username@hostname:port`) are *identical* for the gitolite and username entries. They're both `git@hostname:port`! Once I realized that, it was an easy fix. Simply add distinguishing elements into a more specific `ControlPath` entry for those two users. E.g.,

```
Host gitolite
    HostName <whatever> 
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/gitolite-admin-%r@%h:%p

Host username
    HostName <whatever> 
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/username
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/gitolite-username-%r@%h:%p
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add `git` (the user) to the line which begins with `AllowUsers`.
Then I had to add git to a sysadmin group that was also allow on sshd_config's line that begins with `AllowGroups`.

Don't forget to restart the ssh daemon with `sudo service ssh restart`.

Note : I didn't have to `ssh-copy-id` or add the public key to `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` as suggested before (gitolite's developer recommends against this btw.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with a different solution because of my config. I setup my gitolite user as “git” so I needed to do `git clone git@server:repo.git`