# Binding a subdomain to a directory without apache (available through ssh)

Tags: git, ssh, subdomain, subdirectory

I know how to bind a domain/subdomain to a directory using apache, through virtualhost. I would like to do the same operation without using apache and http. Something that can work using ssh or git protocol. I can't find any data on the internet.

Especially, on github, to clone a repository, you can use "git@github.com:symfony/symfony.git", I'm pretty sure that users managing repositories aren't stored at / .

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way it can work with ssh is when you are using the [ssh **forced command** mechanism](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858) which will call a script with:

- your git command (clone, push, pull)
- your repo name (deduced from the git command)

That script *knows* where the repos are.

One example of such an approach is done with **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)** (see **[how does gitolite works](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/how.html)**).
The [.gitolite.rc it generates](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L40-L42) during its installation will put all the bare rpeos at `~/repositories`:

```
$rc{GL_REPO_BASE} = "$ENV{HOME}/repositories";
```

Yet, with the appropriate `~/.ssh/config` file on the client side, you would clone a gitolite repo with:

```
git clone gitolite:myrepo
```

More details at "[users are asked for password while using gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909791/6309)".

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer. Obviously, I saw this kind of answer browing the internet. But the forced command was for sftp, i thought this was irrelevant for my case. Anyway, thank you, I'll study that right now.

Comment: @pataprout I have edited the answer with more details on gitolite. You can see my installation script for gitolite at https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh