# Can't work properly with Gitosis

Tags: git, ssh-keys, gitosis

I ask to help with a strange error during my work with Git.

I've installed Gitosis. Here's my config:

```
cat /root/gitosis-admin/gitosis.conf 
[gitosis]
loglevel = DEBUG

[group gitosis-admin]
writable = gitosis-admin
members = admin

[group sugar-dev]
writable = sugar-dev
members = eyablokov
```

So I pointed one SSH key, "admin", to administering Gitosis. Also I've created "sugar-dev" repo and pointed another key as member. "admin" key is on one machine, and it's okay. Second, "eyablokov" key is an usual member key on my another machine. I plan use this key as dev only.

I've configured and pushed the changes into gitosis-admin repo by the normal way. Both keys are in keydir/ directory and was pushed remote also.

After this, on another machine, where "eyablokov" key is stored, I create a local directory: `mkdir ~/Projects/sugar-dev`. Enter into: `cd ~/Projects/sugar-dev`. Next: `git init`, and after: `git remote add origin git@SERVER:sugar-dev.git`. It's okay.

After I try, for example, add something and commit and push and have a problem:

```
echo 'Please, describe the project.' > DESCRIPTION
git add DESCRIPTION 
git commit -am "Added description file"
```

And `git push origin master` shows me

```
Pushing to git@SERVER:sugar-dev.git
fatal: cannot exec '/Users/gular/.ssh/eyablokov_dsa': Permission denied
fatal: unable to fork
```

I don't know what to do. git must to see my eyablokov, not eyablokov_dsa, key. dsa is another my key. I've tried to chmod, tried to move .ssh/config file, where is IdentityFile pointed to dsa key. Didn't help.

Comment: Now I'm waiting for another developer. I want to give him an access to sugar-dev with his key, and see what will be. I think it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with an ssh-based git server (like gitosis, or better yet, [gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358) since gitosis is obsolete and no longer maintained), you need a `~/.ssh/config` file in order to specify the exact ssh key file names you want to use.
(also illustrated in "[users are asked for password while using gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909791/6309)")

In your case:

```
Host eyablokov
    HostName SERVER 
    User git
    IdentityFile /Users/gular/.ssh/eyablokov
```

That allows you to use this kind of url:

```
git clone eyablokov:sugar-dev.git
```

On Windows, make sure you are using a [git-cmd.bat](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) instance (included with msysgit), which will correctly set your `HOME` environment variable (not set by default by Windows).