# Setting up gitolite: FATAL: R any gitolite-admin gitolite denied by fallthru

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

I'ved tried what I've found here:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843781/gitolite-adding-user-not-working-and-denied-by-fallthru-when-cloning-as-root)

[And this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976239/cannot-clone-repository-fatal-r-any-gitolite-admin-gitolite-denied-by-fallthru)

I've generated my ssh keys with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f gitolite
```

I then copy them to gitolite server

```
scp gitolite.pub git@my-server.com:gitolite.pub
```

After that I setup gitolite on my server with no apparent errors

```
gitolite setup -pk gitolite.pub
```

The only key in my .gitolite/keydir/ is gitolite.pub. The only one listed in .ssh/authorized_keys is my gitolite.pub.

On my client side I setup a ssh config file as such

```
host gitolite
    user git
    hostname my-server.com
    identityfile ~/.ssh/gitolite
```

I then run

```
git clone gitolite:gitolite-admin.git
```

which gives me:

```
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
FATAL: R any gitolite-admin gitolite DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access right and the repository exists.
```

What should I try next to fix this issue?

EDIT:

IF it helps at all I can clone testing.git just fine this way.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by completely removing gitolite from my server and reinstaling it. It's good to note that when you generate your keys they need to be the name of the user that you are currently logged in as on your client workstation.